# How to Subtract Hours from Now() in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

What is the simplest way to Subtract 9 Hours from NOW() in VB .NET?

I am using NOW() function in VB .NET to get the Current DateTime in the below mentioned format:

"12/5/2014 9:24:47 PM"

I want to Subtract 9 Hours from the DateTime.

Thanks

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-9)` => Have you even tried searching for it???

Comment: `Dim dt2 = Now.AddHours(-9)`  or `dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-9)` using the NET DateTime type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-9)
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx for a list of methods.

Comment: Just remove the `;` to make it vb.net.  :)